# Possible to keep fraction in a query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for a way to add up averages in SQL. Here is an example of the data I have:

```
product      avg_price
phone        104.28
car          1000.00
```

And I'm looking to build something like this:

```
product      avg_price
[all]        544.27
phone        104.28
car          1000.00
```

The way I'm currently doing it is to store the count and sum in two different columns, such as:

```
product    cnt     total
phone      203     20,304.32
car        404     304,323.30
```

And from that get the average. However, I was wondering if it is possible in SQL to just 'keep the fraction' and be able to add them as needed. For example:

```
product      avg_price
[all]        [add the fractions]
phone        20,304.32 / 203
car          304,323.30 / 404
```

Or do I need to use two columns in order to get an average of multiple aggregated rows?

Comment: obviously you need both count and total for each row! will you store it in two columns or in one (as a struct for example) is totally up to you. as on option you can have avg and either count or total for each row - so you will be able to recompute missing attribute

Comment: This is more a mathematical than a programming questions: yes, you will need two columns.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 columns to get the average, but if you want to display as a fraction then you will need both numbers.  They don't need to be in 2 columns though.

```
    select product, sum(total) ||'/'||sum(count) 
    from table a
        join table b on a.product=b.product
    union
    select product, total ||'/'||count 
    from table a
        join table b on a.product=b.product;
```